# What are chemicals that would harm a person, but not one of flight?

Tags: biology, chemistry

So, one of my characters are trapped by a bunch of people. He's a mutant that evolved to be able to fly. (A pair of bat-like wings, hollow bones, air sacks, etc) His friend needs to cause a distraction. Are there any toxic chemicals that could harm normal people, but a person of flight could get off with little to no damage?

Comment: I think the answer here requires some more specifics on the exact biology. If the mutant (besides the wings and bones) has the same chemical biology, then chemicals will have the same effect.

Comment: Hot lava. Make the ground into hot lava.

Comment: Ironically its oxygen (super high concentration) so the only way out is up!

Answer (score 8):

The obvious answer is any heavier-than-air poisonous gas.

Even something inert like Xenon would work to induce unconsciousness, though if you want to get nasty you could use mustard gas or all sorts of other chemical warfare.

I am *not* going to do research into which would be plausible to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming common biology (apart from the flying) the answer is probably 'No'. It does depend somewhat on the precise circumstances, but the only likely answer is a heavy poisonous gas, as o11c proposes.

The problem with a poisonous gas is that, in the question, it would appear to be necessary to disable the other people close by, in order to enable our winged person to escape - if they are disabled before his escape, then so would he.

Furthermore, since winged flight requires a significant downthrust to achieve flight, this itself would likely disperse the poisonous gas, and the fact that flight itself is relatively strenuous, our flying chap is going to be more vulnerable than others to any gas breathed in (even if partly dispersed).

If the gas is deployed afterwards, then he might escape by simply just not being there below, but that doesn't seem to be the scenario.